# Repeating a suspend function / method

Tags: java, kotlin

How can I repeat a suspend function after a 10 seconds delay?

#### Code

```
suspend fun ethPriceRequestFun(): Double { ... here is the code }
```

```
fun callRequest() = runBlocking { running the ethPriceRequestFun function}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    callRequest()
}
```

Here `ethPriceRequestFun` is suspend function which runs computed value with small delay.

```
suspend fun ethPriceRequestFun(int: Int): Int {
    delay(10)
    return int*20
}
```

From `callRequest` function you are calling `ethPriceRequestFun` repeatedly with delay of one second.

```
fun callRequest() = runBlocking{
    repeat(5) {
        delay(1.toDuration(DurationUnit.SECONDS))
        println(ethPriceRequestFun(it))
    }
}
```

Here the output will be like this.

***0
20
40
60
80***

Here repeat is a loop which runs 5 times. So indices will be (0,1,2,3,4).
In `ethPriceRequestFun` we multiple the value by 20 and print.
These numbers will be printed with one second delay after each.

Make sure to import this.

> import kotlin.time.toDuration

Hope it helps.